# Why method of class does not have access to some field of my class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, smart-pointers, type-inference

I try to implement `linked_ptr`. It is a study task. It is a part of my code:

```
template <class T>
class linked_ptr 
{
public:
    //***************
    linked_ptr<T>(linked_ptr<T> const& other)
    {
        p = other.p;

        left_ptr = &other;
        right_ptr = other.right_ptr;

        if (other.right_ptr != nullptr)
        {
            (other.right_ptr)->left_ptr = this;
        }

        other.right_ptr = this;
    }

    template <class U>
    linked_ptr<T>(linked_ptr<U> const& other)
    {
        p = other.p;

        left_ptr = &other;
        right_ptr = other.right_ptr;

        if (other.right_ptr != nullptr)
        {
            (other.right_ptr)->left_ptr = this;
        }

        other.right_ptr = this;
    }

private:
    T *p;
    mutable linked_ptr const* left_ptr;
    mutable linked_ptr const* right_ptr;
};


class A
{
public:
    int a = 0;
    A(int aa)
    {
        a = aa;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(int bb)
    {
        a = bb;
    }
};

int main()
{
    linked_ptr<B> a(new B(5));
    linked_ptr<A> b(a);

    return 0;
}
```

I have some errors:

```
cannot access private member declared in class 'smart_ptr::linked_ptr<B>'
cannot access private member declared in class 'smart_ptr::linked_ptr<B>'   
cannot access private member declared in class 'smart_ptr::linked_ptr<B>'
cannot access private member declared in class 'smart_ptr::linked_ptr<B>'
cannot access private member declared in class 'smart_ptr::linked_ptr<B>'
cannot access private member declared in class 'smart_ptr::linked_ptr<B>'
ptr::linked_ptr<B> *' to 'const smart_ptr::linked_ptr<A> *'
ptr::linked_ptr<B> *' to 'const smart_ptr::linked_ptr<A> *'
linked_ptr<A> *const ' to 'const smart_ptr::linked_ptr<B> *'
linked_ptr<A> *const ' to 'const smart_ptr::linked_ptr<B> *'
```

I don't know what these errors are related. It is interesting, that `linked_ptr<T>(linked_ptr<T> const& other)` works well, but `linked_ptr<T>(linked_ptr<U> const& other)` does not.

How can I fix these problems? Can I to combine two copy constructors in one?

P.S. Of course, `U` is a child of `T`.

Comment: Normally, errors like that will give a line number; it would help greatly if you indicate *where* these errors are happening in your code.

Comment: @Hurkyl, all errors occur in `linked_ptr<T>(linked_ptr<U> const& other)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `T` and `U` are different types, then `linked_ptr<T>` and `linked_ptr<U>` are different types. This means they can not see the private members of the other.

You need to make other `linked_ptr`s friends:

```
template <class T>
class linked_ptr {
    // The rest...

    template<class U>
    friend class linked_ptr;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a class, you have a *class template.* That is, a template, a recipe, for creating classes. In goes a type (for `T`) and out goes a class. A totally distinct, separate class for each `T`. Just like classes `A` and `B` cannot access each other's private fields, neither can classes `linked_ptr<A>` and `linked_ptr<B>` (and `linked_ptr<int>`, for that matter).

If you need this access, you must add the appropriate `friend` declaration to your class template:

```
template <class T>
class linked_ptr 
{
  template <class U>
  friend class linked_ptr;
// ... the rest as before
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions only address the first compile error. Using a template friend declaration will allow `linked_ptr<A>` to access `linked_ptr<B>` private state, but they will not allow you to assign a `linked_ptr<A> *` to a `linked_ptr<B> *`.

The tree itself should be composed uniformly of the base type.

```
int main()
{
    linked_ptr<A> a(new B(5));
    linked_ptr<A> b(a);

    return 0;
}
```

If you do it this way, you don't need the friend declaration. (Or you need to make the constructor more sophisticated, morphing the `link_ptr<U>` to a `linked_ptr<T>`. But that requires smarter pointers or clones or something... which brings up: I'm not sure what is "smart" about these pointers. As presented, no memory management is being done and the `new B(5)` is lost.)

Also, I know this is just pseudocode, but the `B::B(int bb)` constructor needs to explicitly initialize its base:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    B(int bb)
    : A(bb)
    {
    }
};
```

One practices I see in your code that may add to the confusion it the declaration of `left_ptr` and `right_ptr` as `linked_ptr`. C++ allows you to refer to the class by its template name inside the definition, but that doesn't mean that its a good idea. I think the code (and the above mistake) are more clear if the code is written as:

```
T *p;
mutable linked_ptr<T> const* left_ptr;
mutable linked_ptr<T> const* right_ptr;
```

Comment: if you want to know more about this type of smart pointer, you can read this link: https://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/source/browse/trunk/src/processor/linked_ptr.h

Comment: In that case ownership appears to be tracked by a linked list of non-templated types, the `linked_ptr_internal`. There is no attempt to assign a `linked_ptr<U>` to a `linked_ptr<T>` in the templated copy constructor as a result. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the tree but perhaps making the ownership management non-templated should be examined.